# How can I find such non-trivial functions $f(n)$ and $g(n)$?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, summation

Is it possible to find such a function $f:\mathbb{N_{>0}}\longrightarrow \left\{0,1,2 \right\}$ or a sequence  $f(n):= x_n$ and such a function $g:\mathbb{N_{>0}}\longrightarrow \left\{0,1,2 \right\}$ or a sequence $g(n):= y_n$ which gives

> $$\lim_{n \to \infty }\text{sup}\dfrac{\displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^{n} \left(5^k \times f(k)  \right)}{\displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^{n} \left(5^k \times g(k)  \right)}=\infty$$

I know only trivial solutions, for example let, $g(k)$ be a constant function, where $g(k)=0$ and let  $f(k)$ be a constant function, where $f(k)=2$.

But I`m looking for a non-constant functions which provide the conditions of the problem. How can I find such non-trivial functions?

> I tried $f(k)= k\mod3$   $\quad$ and  $\quad$ $g(k)=k^2 \mod3 $
>   $f(k)= k^2 \mod 2$  $\quad$  and  $\quad$$g(k)=k \mod 3$  $\thinspace$ and similar elementary functions, which that doesn`t work.

Comment: Try $f(k)=(k\mod 2) +1$ and $g(k)=\bigl\lfloor-\text{frac}\bigl(\sqrt{k}\bigr)\bigr\rfloor+1$, where $\text{frac}(x)$ is the fractional part of a real number $x$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose $f(k)\ne 0$ when $k$ is $1$ less than a  perfect square, but $g(k)=0$ except when $k$ is a perfect square. When  $n=(m+1)^2-1$ we have $$\sum_{k=1}^n5^kf(k)\ge 5^nf(n)\ge 5^n=5^{m^2+2m}\quad .... (I)$$ but $$\sum_{k=1}^n5^kg(k)= \sum_{j=1}^m5^{j^2}g(j^2)\le m\cdot 5^{m^2}\cdot 2\quad ....(II).$$ The ratio of the far RHS of $(I)$ to $(II)$ is $\frac {5^{2m}}{2m},$ which $\to \infty$ as $m$ (... and hence also as $n=(m+1)^2-1 ...)\to \infty.$

Comment: Please, can you write the first 10 terms of this sequences?

Comment: I can't, because they are not unique. It doesn't matter what member of $\{0,1,2\}$ is $f(n)$ when $n\in \{1,2,4,5,6,7,9,10\}$ as long as $f(3)$ and $f(8)$ are in $\{1,2\}.$ And $g(n)\in \{1,2\}$ when $n\in \{1,4,9\}$ but $g(n)=0 $ when $n\in \{2,3,5,6,7,8,10\}.$

Comment: But is it true that range of both functions you find can only take values ​​of $0, 1$ and $2?$

Comment: Now, I understood. Thank you very much.

Comment: Your argument works for any finite number  $5^k, 7^k,3^k..$ am I right?

Comment: For any number greater than 1, yes.

Comment: Thank you for comment..My last question:) Do you think Is it possible to find such an argument for at least heuristic only binary functions? I mean $f(n), g(n) \in\left\{0,1\right\}$ Thank you again.

Comment: The example in my A works for binary-valued f,g.

Comment: I didn't fully understand your last comment, but thank you.