# Is it possible to find infinitely many computable and non-computable functions that provide the following conditions?

Tags: calculus, limits, summation, infinity, computability

Let,

> a) $f:\mathbb{N}\longrightarrow \left\{0,1,2 \right\}$ or a sequence  $f(n):= x_n$ where $x_n\in \left\{0,1,2\right\}$ and $g:\mathbb{N}\longrightarrow \left\{0,1,2 \right\}$ or a sequence $g(n):= y_n$ where $y_n\in \left\{0,1,2\right\}$
>
> b)  $f:\mathbb{N}\longrightarrow \left\{0,1 \right\}$ or a sequence  $f(n):= x_n$ where $x_n\in \left\{0,1\right\}$ and $g:\mathbb{N}\longrightarrow \left\{0,1 \right\}$ or a sequence $g(n):= y_n$ where $y_n\in \left\{0,1\right\}$

Question-1.

- Is it possible to find such non-trivial functions $f(n)$ and $g(n)$, which gives

> $\qquad$ $\qquad$ $\displaystyle \lim_{k \to \infty }\dfrac{\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{k} \left(m^n \times f(n)  \right)}{\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{k} \left(m^n \times g(n)  \right)}=\infty$ $\qquad$  and $\qquad$ $\displaystyle \lim_{k \to \infty }\dfrac{\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{k} \left(m^n \times g(n)  \right)}{\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{k} \left(m^n \times f(n)  \right)}=0$
>
> where, $m\in\mathbb{Z^{+}}, m \geq 3.$

Or without a unique limit point:

> $\qquad$ $\quad$ $\displaystyle \lim_{k \to \infty }\text{sup}\dfrac{\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{k} \left(m^n \times f(n)  \right)}{\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{k} \left(m^n \times g(n)  \right)}=\infty$ $\qquad$  and $\quad$ $\displaystyle \lim_{k \to \infty }\text{inf}\dfrac{\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{k} \left(m^n \times g(n)  \right)}{\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{k} \left(m^n \times f(n)  \right)}=0$
>
> where, $m\in\mathbb{Z^{+}}, m \geq 3.$

For example let, $f(n)$ and $g(n)$ be constant functions, where $g(n)=0$ and $f(n)=1$ or $f(n)=2$ which works.

But, I`m looking for a non-constant or non-trivial functions which provide the conditions of the problem. How can I find such  functions?

But, we can choose infinitely many computable functions, for example $f(n)= n\mod3$   $\quad$ and $g(n)=n^2 \mod3 $   which doesn`t work. In fact, it is much easier to find such functions!

Then, I have $2$ more short questions.

> Question-2.
>
> - Is it possible to find infinitely many computable and non-computable functions that provide these conditions?
>
> Question-3.
>
> - Is it possible to find such functions $f(n)$ and $g(n)$ which given by a unique mathematical formula?

This question is related to the question [I asked before.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3475506/548054)

But, the new question is different and expressed  more detailed here.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Let Z, be the set of functions from $\mathbb N$ to $\{0,1,2\}$ such that they are ultimately zero constant $$g\in Z \Leftrightarrow \exists N,\forall n\ge N, g(n)=0$$

Then you can easily prove that $f$ and $g$ verify the limits if and only if $g\in Z$ and $f\notin Z$.

Hence, as $Z$ contains only recursive functions, $g$ must be recursive. However, $f$ can be recursive or not.